# How can I make icon '+' on create button in react-admin?

Tags: reactjs, react-admin

I have some problem with default view of button create. When the screen is more than 900px width we will see button create with label "CREATE". When the screen is less than 900px we will see button create as icon "+". I'd like to see button create as icon "+" all the time. Please, help.

```
export function Content() {
    const dataProvider = useDataProvider();
    const sellerId = useSellerId();
    return (
        <Admin dataProvider={dataProvider} layout={CustomLayout}>
            <Resource
                name="seller"
                list={MenuItems}
                create={<CreateMenuItem sellerId={sellerId} />}
                edit={<EditMenuItem sellerId={sellerId} />}
                options={{ label: 'Menu' }}
            />
            <CustomRoutes>
                <Route path="/profile" element={<SellerInfo />} />
                <Route path="/images" element={<ImagesManager />} />
            </CustomRoutes>
        </Admin>
    );
}
```

Comment: Assuming you are talking about the create button in the List component, you can customize the list actions by following [this doc](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/List.html#actions). Have a look at the [CreateButton source code](https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/blob/master/packages/ra-ui-materialui/src/button/CreateButton.tsx) for inspiration on how to make your own create button.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try to understand

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tried this myself but you could try to create your own custom button because the `Create` label is on the `CreateButton` by default:

```js
import { Admin, Resource, CreateButton, TopToolbar, List } from 'react-admin';

const CreateMenuItemButton = () => <CreateButton resource="seller" label="" />;

const MenuItemActions = () => (
    <TopToolbar>
        <CreateMenuItemButton />
    </TopToolbar>
);

const MenuItems = () => (
    <List actions={<MenuItemActions />}>
        ...
    </List>
);

export function Content() {
    const dataProvider = useDataProvider();
    const sellerId = useSellerId();
    return (
        <Admin dataProvider={dataProvider} layout={CustomLayout}>
            <Resource
                name="seller"
                list={MenuItems}
                create={<CreateMenuItem sellerId={sellerId} />}
                edit={<EditMenuItem sellerId={sellerId} />}
                options={{ label: 'Menu' }}
            />
            <CustomRoutes>
                <Route path="/profile" element={<SellerInfo />} />
                <Route path="/images" element={<ImagesManager />} />
            </CustomRoutes>
        </Admin>
    );
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work. `
    const CreateMenuItemButton = () => <CreateButton resource="seller" label="fgnjfhj" />;
    const MenuItemActions = () => (
        <TopToolbar>
            <CreateMenuItemButton />
        </TopToolbar>
    );

    return (
        <Admin dataProvider={dataProvider} layout={CustomLayout}>
            <Resource
                name="seller"
                list={MenuItems}
                edit={<EditMenuItem sellerId={sellerId} />}
                options={{ label: 'Menu' }}
            />
            <MenuItemActions sellerId={sellerId} />`

Comment: I am unsure what the problem is, but the code in your comment looks weird. I can't see a closing parentheses after the return statement and the `MenuItemActions` component should not be inside the `Content` component. I updated my answer to make things a bit more clear.